# Unique Linux system identifier

Tags: linux, hexadecimal

I’m encouraging my students to install a Linux distro in their computers. To be sure they have completed the task, I ask them to execute this command to generate a unique identifier:

```
echo $(sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g') $(ifconfig | grep -oP 'HWaddr \K.*' | sed 's/://g') | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

…and send me the hexadecimal string obtained.

Now, a number of students are providing the same string. Can it be that this string is not unique for every installation? (I obtain a different one in every machine), or are they cheating?

Comment: If you wish your students to provide you with a unique number proving they installed their own version of Linux, you should ask them for their disk UUID number, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. You may ask they run a command like `uuidgen` and check that the three leftmost parts are hexadecimal numbers, while the two rightmost ones are just octal.

Comment: Good. Although I don't quite get the verification step. I obtain five hexadecimals when running the command, how can I know that it's a valid UUID? The last two are not octals, plus, every time the command is run, it will generate a different UUID, providing any student with a method for distributing UUID among mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible actually: the two computers I have at home don't have `dmidecode` installed, and `ifconfig` is not in the `PATH` for regular users, so I get the same string on both:

```
01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
```

Is that the ID your students were giving you?

You should consider adding `sudo` in front of `ifconfig` command, and perhaps add something date-related, like `stat /bin/sh | grep Change`. Still, if you don't trust your students, how do you plan to verify that the ID they provide correspond to a real system?

Comment: Correct, that string is the most frequent one. I really don't have a method to verify that it's a valid identifier, just assume that they won't be willing to go that far. Do you know of any method to do a reliable verification of the task?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify them by getting the serial number of the hdd.

```
lsblk --nodeps -no serial /dev/sda
```

The example serial number is **6VEHJPW7**.

Comment: As it's written, the command does not work in my system.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: otherwise you can use '/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT'

Comment: This is what I get (Ubuntu 14.04): `lsblk: unknown column: serial`, on a lubuntu system it works just fine...

Comment: Im using lubuntu and Im using these commands for disk identification. You can try find an alternative commands for Ubuntu 14.04